# Invoice generated from multiple places handling database model

Tags: sql, database, linq, database-design

I have an invoice management system. It has quotation, sales order, purchase order

The user has the option to generate invoices from multiple places

1. quotation when it is approved
2. sales order when it is accepted by the customer
3. purchase order directly can be converted to invoice

I have a table and there subtables likes this

1. quotations, quotations items
2. sales order, sales order items
3. purchase order, purchase order items
4. invoice, invoice items

How can I keep record of where the invoice is generated without breaking the relationships?

Answer (score 1):

In the Invoice table created two new columns:

```
InvoiceSource VARCHAR(100)
InvoiceSourceID INT
```

Modify your code to store the source and Id of what created the Invoice. For example, if an invoice is generated from a quotation with primary key 1009. The following will exist in the invoice table:

```
InvoiceId|InvoiceSource|InvoiceSourceID|...
----------------------------------------
     1200|  'QUOTATION'|           1009|...
```

Subsequently if a Sales Order with Id 1346 is converted to an Invoice the following will exist in the invoice table:

```
InvoiceId|InvoiceSource|InvoiceSourceID|...
----------------------------------------
     1200|  'QUOTATION'|           1009|...
     1201| 'SALESORDER'|           1346|...
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the link in the sql server database would be missing

Comment: @maztt, when you say "link" what are you referring to?

Comment: Also, what are the current foreign keys?

Comment: by link i mean the relationships that you specify in sql server database

Comment: basically what i mean to say that your solution is more of a nosql solution

Comment: Actually this a data modeling pattern that many Enterprise Software  Platforms use that encounter this problem. Another other way would involve creating a foreign key for each of the data tables listed and populating they key. In the industry my solution is more common.